# How to define folder name when saving json file in Python?

Tags: python

How to define folder name when saving JSON file?
I tried to add `myfoldername` inside `open()`, but did not work.
Also tried to `myfoldername/myfilename` in filename definition

Error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Code:

```
import json

# Testing file save
dictionary_data = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

filename = "myfilename" +  time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".json"
a_file = open("myfoldername",filename, "w")
json.dump(dictionary_data, a_file)
a_file.close()
```

Comment: You should be using `pathlib.Path` objects, or at least `os.path` to handle creating paths. But basic string formatting would work, e.g. `f"myfoldername/{myfilename}"` or `"myfoldername/" + filename`...

Comment: `open("myfoldername"+filename, "w")`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

- Use `pathlib` to manage paths
- Create the parent dir if not exist with `mkdir`
- Open the file thanks to the `with` statement

```
import json
import time
from pathlib import Path

# Testing file save
dictionary_data = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

filename = Path("myfilename") / Path(f"{time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}.json")
# create the parent dir if not exist
filename.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

with open(filename, "w") as a_file:
    json.dump(dictionary_data, a_file)
```